# Unable to use ISA11 as repetition separator when converting 4010 to 5010 file in BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, edi

I'm creating a simple BizTalk 2010 process that will convert a 4010 835 file to 5010 format. I have a receive port that accepts the 4010 835, and a send port to drop the 5010 version to. There's a map attached to the receive port, so there's no orchestration involved. There's only a single party, with the typical THEM -> US and US -> THEM tabs.

Everything works fine when tested; the file is properly mapped, and all my settings (ISA & GS values) on the US -> THEM tab are added to the outbound file. The problem occurs when I try to set the ISA11 usage on the US -> THEM tab to Repetition separator: ^ (which is pretty much standard for 5010). At that point the inbound message fails with a bunch of "Invalid character in data element" errors - anywhere that there is a "U" in the file. It's treating the U in the inbound 4010 ISA 11 as a rep. separator.

Any thoughts on why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh, it was my stupid mistake... I'm used to dealing with situations where we switch the ISA06 and ISA08 between the inbound and outbound file, but in this case we're just passing it through, keeping the ISAs the same. So my outbound party configuration was actually picking up the inbound file, treating the U as a repetition separator.

Of course that brings up another question, how would you actually do party configuration if you want the inbound and outbound ISA06 & 08 to be the same, but I'll ask that another time.